# How do SPBasePermissions enumeration values map to the UI user permissions and levels?

Tags: permissions

I'm mapping out and implementing some permissions settings for a site that mostly involve changes through the UI, but at times require some under-the-hood tinkering in SharePoint Designer. I'm a bit new to this and the documentation isn't always clear.

The list of SPBasePermssions Enumerations is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx) and the list of the possible permissions you can set from the UI is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx) Can someone help me map these to each other?

Comment: All of the entries listed in the enum are visible in the Permissions Level page, the entries are named something searchable in the perms levels page. As you said you'd be doing this in SharePoint Designer - can you actually use that enum in SPD?

Comment: You give the wrong link for "permissions in UI" - it points to SharePoint Server permissions while SPBasePermissions enumeration refers to Foundation. Foundation permissions described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure the article below will help you understand the relations between permissions, permission levels, User/Groups and Securable objects;

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287752.aspx

Basically a permission level is a set of individual fine grained permissions that are logically grouped together keeping a certain role in mind.

Permissions themselves are fixed but permission levels can be created/modified and SharePoint creates some permission level for us to get started.

Securable Objects (look aticle above for a fixed set of securable objects that Sharepoint has) are essentially given a perticular permission level to a particular user/group. If concept of permission level was not there, you would have to give individual permissions to sharepoint users/groups for secuarble objects! what a nightmare that would be!